# Remove New Line Character from CSV file's string column

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a CSV File with a string column were that column spans to multiple lines. I want to aggregate those multiple lines into one line.

For example

```
1, "asdsdsdsds", "John"
2, "dfdhifdkinf
dfjdfgkdnjgknkdjgndkng
dkfdkjfnjdnf", "Roy"
3, "dfjfdkgjfgn", "Rahul"
```

I want my output to be

```
1, "asdsdsdsds", "John"
2, "dfdhifdkinf dfjdfgkdnjgknkdjgndkng dkfdkjfnjdnf", "Roy"
3, "dfjfdkgjfgn", "Rahul"
```

I want to achieve this output using PowerShell

Thanks.

Comment: Is the missing double quote at the end of line 2 column 2 intentional or is that a typo? May the strings contain commas?

Comment: typo...Sorry for that.
Corrected that!

Comment: How can it be done in PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$csv = 'C:\path\to\your.csv'

(Import-Csv $csv -Header 'ID','Value','Name') | % {
  $_.Value = $_.Value -replace "`r`n",' '
  $_
} | Export-Csv $csv -NoTypeInformation
```

If your CSV contains headers, remove `-Header 'ID','Value','Name'` from the import and replace `Value` with the actual column name.

If you don't want double quotes around the fields, you can remove them by replacing `Export-Csv` with something like this:

```
... | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | % { $_ -replace '"' } | Out-File $csv
```

To remove the header from the output you add another filter before `Out-File` to skip the first line:

```
... | select -Skip 1 | Out-File $csv
```

Comment: In addition to above question, I have double quotation marks on each column. In the same script, how can double quotation marks be replaced with blank character?

Comment: Thank you Ansgar!!
One small question, is there a way to remove header from the CSV Output?

Comment: When I try to open newly created csv file in excel, it opens up only in one column. How can that be resolved?

Comment: That would be a new question, and one for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) at that. The problem may have to do with the file's extension, which separator you chose, and how you open the file in Excel.

Comment: I am not sure, but the above command is not working to remove new line character from one of the column of the csv file.

Comment: Perhaps it's just a single LF character, not the Windows default CR-LF? Try ``-replace "`r" -replace "`n",' '`` instead of ``-replace "`r`n",' '``.

Comment: Yes, I printed each character using C# code and figured that out.

Answer (score 5):

Building on Ansgar's answer, here's how to do it when:

- You don't know the column names
- Your CSV file may contain CR or LF independently

  ```
  (Import-Csv $csvInput) | % {
      $line = $_
      foreach ($prop in $line.PSObject.Properties) {
          $line.($prop.Name) = ($prop.Value -replace '[\r\n]',' ')
      }
      $line
  } | Export-Csv $csvOutput -NoTypeInformation
  ```

Answer (score 2):

You can import the csv, do a specialized select, and write the result into a new CSV.

```
import-csv Before.csv -Header "ID","Change" | Select ID,@{Name="NoNewLines", Expression={$_.Change -replace "`n"," "}} | export-csv After.csv
```

The key part is in the select statement, which allows you to pass a specialized hash table (Name is the name of the property, Expression is a scriptblock that computes it).

You may need to fiddle with headers a bit to get the exact output you want.

Comment: The hashtable-as-property-definition technique is now properly documented in the conceptual [about_Calculated_Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties) help topic. To replace both CRLF and LF newlines, use ``'\r?\n'`` instead of ``"`n"``

Answer (score 0):

The problems with Export-CSV are twofold:

- Early versions (powershell1 & 2) do not allow you to append data to the CSV
- If the data being piped to it contains newline characters, the data is useless in Excel

The solution to both of the above is to use Convertto-CSV instead. Here is a sample:

```
{bunch of stuff} | ConvertTo-CSV | %{$_ -replace "`n","<NL>"} | %{$_ -replace "`r","<CR>"} >>$AppendFile
```

Note that this allows you to do whatever editing on the data (in this case, replacing newline data), and using redirecrors to append.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: I've created a CSV Cleaner: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32016543/361842

This can be used to replace any unwanted characters / should be straight-forward to adapt to your needs.

Code copied below; though I recommend referring to the above thread to see any feedback from others.

```
clear-host
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.IO") | out-null
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.VisualBasic") | out-null

function Clean-CsvStream {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [string]$CsvRow
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [char]$Delimiter = ','
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [regex]$InvalidCharRegex 
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [string]$ReplacementString 

    )
    begin {
        [bool]$IsSimple = [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($InvalidCharRegex) 
        if(-not $IsSimple) {
            [System.IO.MemoryStream]$memStream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
            [System.IO.StreamWriter]$writeStream = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($memStream)
            [Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser]$Parser = new-object Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser($memStream)
            $Parser.SetDelimiters($Delimiter)
            $Parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = $true
            [long]$seekStart = 0
        }
    }
    process {
        if ($IsSimple) {
            $CsvRow
        } else { #if we're not replacing anything, keep it simple
            $seekStart = $memStream.Seek($seekStart, [System.IO.SeekOrigin]::Current) 
            $writeStream.WriteLine($CsvRow)
            $writeStream.Flush()
            $seekStart = $memStream.Seek($seekStart, [System.IO.SeekOrigin]::Begin) 
            write-output (($Parser.ReadFields() | %{$_ -replace $InvalidCharRegex,$ReplacementString }) -join $Delimiter)
        }
    }
    end {
        if(-not $IsSimple) {
            try {$Parser.Close(); $Parser.Dispose()} catch{} 
            try {$writeStream.Close(); $writeStream.Dispose()} catch{} 
            try {$memStream.Close(); $memStream.Dispose()} catch{} 
        }
    }
}
$csv = @(
    (new-object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{A="this is regular text";B="nothing to see here";C="all should be good"}) 
    ,(new-object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{A="this is regular text2";B="what the`nLine break!";C="all should be good2"}) 
    ,(new-object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{A="this is regular text3";B="ooh`r`nwindows line break!";C="all should be good3"}) 
    ,(new-object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{A="this is regular text4";B="I've got;a semi";C="all should be good4"}) 
    ,(new-object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{A="this is regular text5";B="""You're Joking!"" said the Developer`r`n""No honestly; it's all about the secret VB library"" responded the Google search result";C="all should be good5"})
) | convertto-csv -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation
$csv | Clean-CsvStream -Delimiter ';' -InvalidCharRegex "[`r`n;]" -ReplacementString ':'
```