# Remove New Line Character from CSV file's string column Shell script

Tags: shell, csv, unix

My problem is exactly same as the one mentioned here

[Remove New Line Character from CSV file's string column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18619939/remove-new-line-character-from-csv-files-string-column)

But what i am looking for is a solution in shell script . I want the broken line to be replaced by newly modified attached line in my file . This is required for me as the RS in my csv file is newline character.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how your echo suppresses a newline (option -n or ending string with \c). A solution is considiring a line as incomplete when it does not end with a double quote.
You can redirect the output to a new file.

```
while read line; do
        if [[ "$line" = *\" ]]; then
                echo "${line}"
        else
                echo -n "${line}"
        fi
done < input
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
sed  '/"[^"][^"]*$/ {
:again
N
s/\n//
/"[^"][^"]*$/ b again
}' input_file
```

`/"[^"][^"]*$/`  searches for unterminated quote

`:again` - a label

`N` - append next line

`s/\n//` - remove newlines

`/"[^"][^"]*$/ b again` - loop if there is still unterminated quote