# Remove New Line from CSV file's string column

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pyspark, newline

I have a CSV file with multiple fields. There are few fields(string) for which data got spans to multiple lines. I want to aggregate those multiple lines into one line.

**Input Data:**

```
1, "asdsdsdsds", "John"
2, "dfdhifdkinf
dfjdfgkdnjgknkdjgndkng
dkfdkjfnjdnf", "Roy"
3, "dfjfdkgjfgn", "Rahul"
```

**Expected Output:**

```
1, "asdsdsdsds", "John"
2, "dfdhifdkinf dfjdfgkdnjgknkdjgndkng dkfdkjfnjdnf", "Roy"
3, "dfjfdkgjfgn", "Rahul"
```

The same question is asked in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18619939/remove-new-line-character-from-csv-files-string-column) earlier. However the solution is achieved using power shell. Is it possible to achieve the same using python or pandas or pyspark.

Whenever the data spans multiple lines it will be in double quotes for sure.

**What I tried**

I can able to read the the data without any issues using pandas and pyspark even though there are fields whose got spanned to multiple lines.

**Pandas:**

```
pandas_df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
```

**PySpark**

```
df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true', inferschema='true') \
        .option("delimiter", ",").option("escape", '\\').option("escape", ':').\
    option("parserLib", "univocity").option("multiLine", "true").load("file.csv")
```

**Edit:**

There can be n number of fields in the csv file and this data span can be in any field.

Comment: "I can able to read the the data without any issues using pandas and pyspark even though there are fields whose got spanned to multiple lines." Then what exactly is the issue?

Comment: I want data(cleansed) in new csv file where multiple lines are into one line.

Answer (score 2):

```
def weird_gen(s):
    s = [s]
    while s:
        *x, a = s[0].split(',', 2)
        y, *s = a.split('\n', 1)
        yield ', '.join(z.strip().replace('\n', ' ') for z in x + [y])

print('\n'.join(weird_gen(open('bad.csv').read())))

1, "asdsdsdsds", "John"
2, "dfdhifdkinf dfjdfgkdnjgknkdjgndkng dkfdkjfnjdnf", "Roy"
3, "dfjfdkgjfgn", "Rahul"
```

Comment: One should not use `.split(',')` to parse CSV files, because a comma may be  within a quoted field.

Comment: You are right.  This is the best I came up with for now.  If someone posts any reasonable answer, I'll likely delete this.

Answer (score 0):

This might help. I am using a simple for loop and negative indexing to get your required result.

```
s = """1, "asdsdsdsds", "John"
2, "dfdhifdkinf
dfjdfgkdnjgknkdjgndkng
dkfdkjfnjdnf", "Roy"
3, "dfjfdkgjfgn", "Rahul"""

res = []

for i in s.split("\n"):
    if i[0].isdigit():
        res.append(i)
    else:
        res[-1] = res[-1] + " " + I

for i in res:
    print(i)
```

**Output**:

```
1, "asdsdsdsds", "John"
2, "dfdhifdkinf dfjdfgkdnjgknkdjgndkng dkfdkjfnjdnf", "Roy"
3, "dfjfdkgjfgn", "Rahul
```

Comment: Hi Rakesh, Thanks for the suggested answer. I updated the question. There can be n number of fields and this data span can be in any field. Could you please suggest the solution.

Comment: Can you provide an example data?

Comment: `1, "asdsdsdsds", "John",3,4,5,"Hi","This is 
 new line data"
2, "dfdhifdkinf dfjdfgkdnjgknkdjgndkng dkfdkjfnjdnf", "Roy",6,7,8,"Hellooo
 ooooooo
   ooooooo", "This"
3, "dfjfdkgjfgn", "Rahul",1,2,3,"Hi
 this is 
  new line data","This is 
   another new line data"`

Comment: the assumption that the first character in every line should be a digit might fail if the string that got spanned on multiple lines contains digits. for example. `1, "some line\n1 plus one equals 2"`